# Add padding-bottom when excerpt goes over a certain limit

Tags: jquery, html, css, conditional-statements

I'm trying to write a jQuery conditional that adds padding to the bottom of a div when the paragraph inside of it is over a certain number of characters. I'm working on a blog and the front page has blog excerpts that overlap each other on mobile if too long. The source code looks something like this:

```
<section class="lcp_catlist">
    <div class="post-left"></div>
    <div class="post-right">
        <a href="#">Blog Title Here</a>
        <p>A long blog excerpt would go here</p>
    </div>
</section>
```

My jQuery to try to tackle this issue is as follows:

```
if ( $('div.post-right p').text().length > 200 ) {
        $(this).parent().parent().css({"padding-bottom" : "45px"});
}
```

Obviously this isn't working. I feel like this is a simple solution that I'm not finding. Can anyone help? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Problem is $(this) is not pointing to ELEMENT , but it points when u write Event like click , So jquery wonders ,what to consider as this

Comment: Is there way to designate that I want the statement in the conditional to the be element that gets the applied CSS?

Comment: var myElement = $('div.post-right p');

if ( myElement.text().length > 200 ) {

myElement.parent().parent().css({"padding-bottom" : "45px"});

}

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of points that look suspicious, I'll outline my thoughts:

**1. The `.text()` method**

```
$('div.post-right p').html().trim().length > 200
```

**2. `$(this)`**

Make sure that this is pointing to the right firing object

**3. The `.parent()` method**

Make sure that the `.parent().parent()` points to the node you want - Chrome's Dev Tools can help here.

**4.  `.css()` alternative syntax**

I'm not sure if this makes a difference, but try these alternatives:

```
.css({paddingBottom: 45px});
```

and the single property syntax

```
.css('paddingBottom', '45px');
```

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, i'd recommend you wrap your

tag where the blog excerpts will be in a span as i don't believe you can add padding to a

tag, also that way you can write one function that will adhere to every blog post element and do something like;

```
<section class="lcp_catlist">
<div class="post-left"></div>
<div class="post-right">
    <a href="#">Blog Title Here</a>
    <span class="blogEntry"><p>A long blog excerpt would go here</p></span>
</div>
</section>
```

and

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.blogEntry').each(function(){
        var charCount = $('.blogEntry').length();
        if(charCount >= 2000){
             $('.blogEntry').css('padding-bottom','20px');
        }
 });
});
```

Comment: Sorry, let me clarify. Based off your example, what I want to happen is if the charcount of blogEntry is > 200, then I want the section.lcp_catlist to receive the padding

Answer (score 0):

In this case, some more of your JS would be helpful. I'm guessing `$(this)` is not the correct element.

I would first define that as a variable and then use that in place of `$(this)` before binding to the `.parent()` method.